# Identify and replace elements in dataframe where the values changes too much from the trend

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace datapoints that change too much in a time series dataframe that is trending downward.

Assuming my data looks something like this:

```
d = {'Health': [100, 90, 80, 20, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How would I go about detecting the change from 80 to 20 is too much and replace it with an appropriate value or just drop the row entirely?

I have tried using `median_filter(df['Health'].values,size=5)` and it works but I want to use a more 'manual' approach to only change values that change past a threshold.

Real data looks like this:

[image: Real data looks like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
THRESHOLD = 25
APPROPRIATE_VALUE = pd.NA
previous_item = 0
for index, item in df['Health'].items():
    if previous_item - item > THRESHOLD:
        df.loc[index, 'Health'] = APPROPRIATE_VALUE
    previous_item = item
```

Go over each index and item in the Health column, check if the previous item minus this item (the drop - or rise, in which case this calculation would be negative) is more than `THRESHOLD`. If so, set the cell in the df with this index and the Health column to `APPROPRIATE_VALUE`.

```py
>>> df
  Health
0    100
1     90
2     80
3   <NA>
4     60
5     50
6     40
7     30
8     20
9     10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkvalues(df,threshold):
    for index in range(1,len(df)-1):
        diff1 = abs(df.loc[index,'Health'] - df.loc[index-1,'Health'])
        print(diff1)
        if diff1>threshold:
            # Drop row or change value here
            df.loc[index,'Health'] = threshold
    return df
```

```
df2 = checkvalues(df,55)
df2
    Health
0   100
1   90
2   80
3   55
4   60
5   50
6   40
7   30
8   20
9   10
```